# Why do most recordings of "Land of Hope and Glory" not include the stanzas?

Tags: classical-music, recording

Looking around recordings of the British Anthem "Land of Hope and Glory" I find that most of them do not include either one of the two stanzas of:

> Dear Land of Hope, thy hope is crowned,
>   God make thee mightier yet!
>   On Sov'ran brows, beloved, renowned,
>   Once more thy crown is set.
>   Thine equal laws, by Freedom gained,
>   Have ruled thee well and long;
>   By Freedom gained, by Truth maintained,
>   Thine Empire shall be strong.

and

> Thy fame is ancient as the days,
>   As Ocean large and wide:
>   A pride that dares, and heeds not praise,
>   A stern and silent pride;
>   Not that false joy that dreams content
>   With what our sires have won;
>   The blood a hero sire hath spent
>   Still nerves a hero son.

But only have the well-known chorus. Why is that so?

Comment: Lines such as "Thine Empire shall be strong" and "The blood a hero sire hath spent" are perhaps viewed as a bit too jingoistic and imperialistic in some quarters?

Comment: Probably a reason similar as to why nobody sings the full Wilhelmus. It's too long and many of the stanzas are archaic at best.

Answer (score 2):

The chorus has simpler words, with a more obvious appeal, and the two verses have quite archaic language. Also, the music for the chorus is what is in Elgar's  [first "Pomp and Circumstance" March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomp_and_Circumstance_Marches#March_No._1_in_D), which is a feature of the annual "Last night of the Proms" concert. The March pre-dates the full anthem.